# Address bar and footer toolbar on iOS 7 don't hide

Tags: ios7, sencha-touch-2.2

As the title of this question says, since iOS7 is here the address bar and footer toolbar in the browser don't hide when I am in my app. I've just tried Safari so far (simulator), but I suspect Chrome will be the same.
I found something similar to a solution for jQuery here: 
http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/52823302883/ios-7-mobile-safari-for-front-end-developers

but I couldn't find yet a solution for my sencha touch app.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Problem seems to be that Safari has changed his behavior with iOS7, now it needs to detect a natural scrolling in the window (no js) to hide the address bar and footer toolbar.
So, that means that if you have a fixed toolbar and footer (very typical in Sencha applications) Safari is not going to detect that scroll at all, because is not a natural scroll.
jQuery mobile has a solution that you can see here if you launch this url in your mobile device: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html

Comment: The only workaround at this time is to tell users to download and use Google Chrome as their browser instead of Safari. Chrome allows full screen browsing.